# Create link to sitemap in footer

Tags: cms, static-block, sitemaps

I am creating all of my footer links in the static block already provided from the magento install. I have managed to delete the links to sitemap advanced search etc below, because i wanted those links to be with the rest of the links in the static block.

I have found a way around to link the contact form from the static block by creating a new contact us cms page and a new template file to hold the form info.

But i am having trouble finding out how i can link to the sitemap page from a static block.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To create a footer link add the following to your theme's `layout/local.xml` file (if it doesn't exist, create it):

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map">
            <label>Site Map</label>
            <url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" />
            <title>Site Map</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but this seems to be the obvious answer to me. (This is code from the CMS Footer from my site, and it works lovely!)

```
<div class="links">
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}contacts/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}terms-and-conditions/">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}catalog/seo_sitemap/category/">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```